# Java regex - quantifier in negative lookbehind

Tags: java, regex

This regex question is kind of an extension of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47809286/how-to-replace-only-some-of-the-matched-substrings)

***Input***

```
String input="first number <start number>123.45<end number> 
               and second number 678.90."
```

***Desired output***

```
String output="first number <start number>123.45<end number> 
               and second number <start number>678.90<end number>."
```

***What I tried***

I have a negative lookback for `<number start>` and a negative lookahead for `<number end>`:

```
String regex="(?<!(<number start>))\\d+(\\.\\d+)?(?!(<number end>))
//             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//            negative lookback                    negative lookahead
//                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                                  float match
```

But the problem is that for a String `<number start>12.34<number end>` it will match on `2.3`.

When I include quantifiers in the lookback I get an error

```
String regex="(?<!(<number start>\\d+))\\d+(\\.\\d+)?(?!(\\d+<number end>))
//             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//            negative lookback                      negative lookahead
//                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                                     float match
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just [`"(?<!<number start>)\\b\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?\\b(?!<number end>)"`](https://regex101.com/r/6xTKBh/1) will work.

Comment: First, this is not a duplicate question. Second, the proposed regex doesn't help.

Comment: @l33t Explain why my suggestion does not help. I provided a regex demo that works correctly: the regex does not match a number inside `<number start>` tags.

Comment: He obviously swapped the tokens.

Comment: @tenticon, try regex-replace (only with group 2) with this: `(<start number>[-+]?\d*\.?\d+<end number>)|([-+]?\d*\.?\d+)`

Comment: @l33t, the regex proposed by @WiktorStribiżew does work. The problem is that the asker of this question mixed the order of the words: `start number` vs. `number start`. However Wiktor's regex makes the assumption that the number is enclosed by `\b`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a limitation of the incredibly slow `lookbehind` feature. For lookbehind, you cannot have an expression matching text of arbitrary length. Which is what the error message tells us.

You could try something like this:

```
(<start number>[-+]?\d*\.?\d+<end number>)|([-+]?\d*\.?\d+)
```

- $1: Matches including the tags.
- $2: Matches excluding the tags.

Then replace text accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of including the `\d` in the existing lookbehind, you can make a new one for it:

```
(?<!<number start>|\d)\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?!\d|<number end>)
```

The pipe character (`|`) in the lookbehind / lookahead is a boolean "or". This solution is similar to what you tried, but does not cause an exception because the lookbehind values have a fixed length.

To explain it a little bit more in detail: Since the regex is supposed to match a decimal number, there must not be leading or trailing digits because they should be part of the match. Therefore they are forbidden (using the negative lookbehind / lookahead) as well.

Live demo: https://regex101.com/r/MdS7rF/1